# search a string in javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: string contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/javascript-string-contains)

I want to search a string in javascript to see if it contain some characters

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var s="hello world";
if(s.contains("hello")) alert("contains");
</script>
```

I may expect a function like **string.contains()** .
Is their a string.contains in javascript or should i use indexOf instead

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/javascript-string-contains duplicate

Comment: this has been asked many times before, you should search for it before asking a question

Answer (score 1):

If you really want a contains:

```
String.prototype.contains = function (searchTerm) {
    return this.toString().indexOf(searchTerm) !== -1;
};
```

If you're feeling fancy:

```
String.prototype.contains = function (searchTerm) {
    return ~this.toString().indexOf(searchTerm);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

indexOf is the way to go - just check the return value.

Answer (score 0):

Try regEx:

```
if( /hello/.test(s) )
    alert("contains");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s.indexOf('hello') > -1
```

[(docs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) or

```
s.match('hello') === true
```

([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), Be aware, that `'hello'` will be interpreted as regular expression in this case.)